# Skyscraper puzzle solver in Java

Tags: java, homework, sudoku

For an assignment, I have created a solver for the [Skyscraper Puzzle](https://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/skyscrapers/rules):

> Each puzzle consists of an N×N grid with some clues along its sides. The object is to place a skyscraper in each square, with a height between 1 and N, so that no two skyscrapers in a row or column have the same number of floors. In addition, the number of visible skyscrapers, as viewed from the direction of each clue, is equal to the value of the clue. Note that higher skyscrapers block the view of lower skyscrapers located behind them.

The puzzle and the ordinances are hard coded into the program. I would like feedback on efficiency and readability. Any and all suggestions are welcome!

**SkyscraperPuzzle.java**

```
package Skyscraper;


/**
 * Write a description of class SkyscraperPuzzle here.
 *
 * @author David White
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class SkyscraperPuzzle {

    private int[][] puzzle = {
        {1, 4, 3, 2},
        {2, 3, 4, 1},
        {4, 2, 1, 3},
        {3, 1, 2, 4}
    };
    private Ordinance[][] ords = {
        {new Ordinance(3, Direction.NORTH), new Ordinance(1, Direction.NORTH), new Ordinance(2, Direction.NORTH), new Ordinance(3, Direction.NORTH)}, //NORTH
        {new Ordinance(2, Direction.SOUTH), new Ordinance(4, Direction.SOUTH), new Ordinance(2, Direction.SOUTH), new Ordinance(1, Direction.SOUTH)}, //SOUTH
        {new Ordinance(3, Direction.EAST), new Ordinance(2, Direction.EAST), new Ordinance(2, Direction.EAST), new Ordinance(1, Direction.EAST)}, //EAST
        {new Ordinance(2, Direction.WEST), new Ordinance(3, Direction.WEST), new Ordinance(1, Direction.WEST), new Ordinance(2, Direction.WEST)} //WEST
    };

    /**
     * Write a constructor to initialize and populate the puzzle and list of ordinances
     * so that the puzzle may be checked to see if it is (correctly) solved.
     */
    public SkyscraperPuzzle() {
        //Puzzle is populated above
        //Ords is populated above
    }

    /**
     * returns the puzzle
     */
    public int[][] getPuzzle() {
        return this.puzzle;
    }

    /**
     * Retuns a 1D array that respresents row r of puzzle
     */
    public int[] getRow(int row) {
        return puzzle[row];
    }

    /**
     * Write a method that returns a 1D array that represents column c of puzzle
     */
    public int[] getColumn(int column) { // row by column
        int[] arr = new int[this.puzzle.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = this.puzzle[i][column];
        }
        return arr;
    }

    /**
     * Write a method that returns true if the 1D array parameter does not contain duplicates
     */
    public boolean noDuplicates(int[] arr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Write a method that returns true if each value from 1 to the number of rows (or columns, they
     * are the same), is contained in the 1D array
     * 
     * if 5x5
     * then 1 2 3 4 5 should all be in array
     */
    public boolean containsOneToN(int[] arr) {
        int[] array = new int[arr.length];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i + 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if(arr[i] == array[j]) {
                    count += 1;
                    array[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return count == arr.length;
    }

    /**
     * Write a method that traverses the 2D array, ords, and returns true if each and
     * every Ordinance requirement is met
     */
    public boolean meetsOrdinances() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++) {
           /* Yet to be implemented */ 
        }
        return false; //used to allow compile
    }

    /**
     * Write a method that returns true if the puzzle is a correctly solved Skyscraper puzzle
     */
    public boolean isSolved() {
        /* Each row and column */
        for(int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++) {
            if(!noDuplicates(this.puzzle[i]) || !noDuplicates(getColumn(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!containsOneToN(this.puzzle[i]) || !containsOneToN(getColumn(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!meetsOrdinances()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Direction.java**

```
package Skyscraper;


/**
 * Enumeration class Direction - write a description of the enum class here
 *
 * @author David White
 * @version (version number or date here)
 */
public enum Direction {
    NORTH, /* Above the 2D array */ 
    SOUTH, /* Below the 2D array */
    EAST, /* Right of the 2D array */
    WEST /* Left of the 2D array */
}
```

**Ordinance.java**

```
package Skyscraper;


/**
 * Write a description of class Ordinance here.
 *
 * @author David White
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Ordinance {

    private int num;
    private Direction direction;

    public Ordinance(int num, Direction direction) {
        this.num = num;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }

    public Direction getDirection() {
        return this.direction;
    }
}
```

---

The `PuzzleTest.java` is used to make sure the methods I've written work in the way they're intended to.

**PuzzleTest.java**

```
package Skyscraper;


/**
 * Write a description of class PuzzleTest here.
 *
 * @author David White
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class PuzzleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SkyscraperPuzzle p = new SkyscraperPuzzle();
        int[][] puzzle = p.getPuzzle();

        /*
         * Outputs entire puzzle
         */
        for(int[] row : puzzle) {
            for(int item : row) {
                System.out.print(item + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        /*
         * Test getColumn method
         * Output should be
         * 1
         * 4
         * 7
         * Status: Successful
         */
        int[] col = p.getColumn(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(col[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        /*
         * Test noDuplicates method
         * Output should be
         * true
         * Status: Successful
         */
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println(p.noDuplicates(arr));
        System.out.println();
        /*
         * Test containsOneToN method
         * Output should be
         * true
         * Status: Successful
         */
        int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println(p.containsOneToN(arr2));

        /*
         * Test meetsOrdinances method
         * Output should be
         * true
         * Status: To be tested
         */

    }

}
```

Comment: @200_success Yes, just edited the post to add the description.

Comment: How can this code ever work if `meetsOrdinances` says `Yet to be implemented`?

Comment: A puzzle solver by definition gets only the clues and then figures out the arrangement of the skyscrapers. I cannot find any code that does this.

Comment: @RolandIllig This assignment in particular has both the skyscrapers and ordinances hardcoded, and just checks if the ordinances match the skyscraper. No user input is involved. And I'm just inquiring about the state of the code now, assuming that `meetOrdinances` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Initialization

The hard-coded nature of the `SkyscraperPuzzle` is a mystery.

I'd move the hard-coded values from `SkyscraperPuzzle` to `PuzzleTest`, and add arguments to the constructor to pass in the puzzle/ordinances.

## No Duplicates

You have an off-by-one error in this function.  While the outer loop runs from `0 ≤ i < N-1`, the inner loop should run from `i+1 ≤ j < N`.  You terminate the inner loop one value too early.

## Contains 1 To N

This function is more complicated than it needs to be.  You are creating an `array[]` with the values from 1 to N.  Then you are looping over the array and testing against the values in `array[j]`.  But we know that `array[j]` will contain `j+1`, so we really don't need the array at all.  You can just search for the required values in succession:

```
public boolean containsOneToN(int[] arr) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == j) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (count != 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

## Is Solved

- You are accessing `puzzle[i]` directly; you should be using `getRow(i)`.
- You are calling `getColumn(i)` multiple times; instead of creating a new object representing the column each time, why not save the column (and row) in a local variable at the start of the loop?

## this

In most cases, `this.` is unnecessary, and can (should) be removed.  The only place it is actually necessary is the `Ordinance` constructor, and even that could be fixed by renaming the constructor parameters.

Comment: Some people like writing `this.` to make it clear that it's an instance variable and not a local variable.

Comment: @200_success Then `this.` needs to be added to where it is missing, like to `puzzle` in `getRow()`.   What about to calls to methods?  Shouldn’t `this.` be added in `isSolved()` to the calls to `noDuplicates()`, `containsOneToN()`, and `getColumn()` to make it clear these are methods on this object?   Adds 15 extra characters to that line.  At what point does the “clarity” become “noise”?  Rhetorical.  I feel it is a terrible “style” and should be squashed as soon as possible, but I know I can’t impose my sense of style on others. (But I can still try.)

Comment: @AJNeufeld There's no avocation for adding it to methods.  There's no need to differentiate between instance methods and local methods because the latter does not exist.

Some people use prefixes like "_" for instance variables, "this." is the same thing.  (Arguably more readable.)